# A list without the conjunction 'and'

Tags: sentence-construction

> Who can calculate the losses left by Sept. 11? [There were] so many
>   wounds to the hearts of the families, so many wounds to the souls of
>   New Yorkers, so many wounds to the peace of Americans

Source: [Six months later](http://www.nytimes.com/2002/03/11/nyregion/a-nation-challenged-survivor-6-months-later-scarred-but-very-alive.html?pagewanted=all)

On a Youtube video an instructor added [There were] to the article in the newspaper but not [and] as I did below.
The pattern above looks like: There were A, B, C, [*and*] D
Why does not he add the conjunction *and* too to showcase a complete English sentence?

Comment: This is an instance of the rhetorical device *asyndeton*, addressed [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/24147/32). It's perfectly grammatical, but should be avoided by learners until they are thoroughly familiar with its effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [rhetorical device](http://literarydevices.net/rhetoric/). As that site puts it

> Rhetorical figures or devices are employed to achieve particular emphasis and effect.

There are many well studied devices. According to StoneyB, this one is called *asyndeton*.

The original is

> Who can calculate the losses left by Sept. 11? So many wounds to the hearts of families, so many wounds to the souls of New Yorkers, so many wounds to the peace of Americans.

By writing the second sentence in this manner, I think the effect is that the author is able to quickly deliver a feeling of loss and pain to the reader.

I believe there is at least another device at work. The one I recognize is called *anaphora*. Notice that the author repeats "so many". I believe the effect of this repetition is to emphasize or convince the reader that the loss suffered on Sept. 11 is **immeasurable** (Who can calculate the losses left by Sept. 11?).

So their is a reason why the *original* author does not write [There were] and [and]. It is to achieve a particular effect. I cannot really comment on why this "YouTube instructor" included [There were] and did not include [and]. Like StoneyB, I also would not recommend trying to use rhetorical devices until you have become a more advanced user.